# Not getting intended results with "either/or" character in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match some fairly simple text but am having trouble with the "|" character. The text is:

`"TF0876 some text Y N 2.31 - 0.01\n TF9788 more text N Y - 2.3 -\n TF1626"`

and I want to extract two items using re.findall:

`"TF0876 some text for  Y N 2.31"` and 
`"TF9788 more text N Y -"`

The code I thought would work is:

```
mat = re.compile(r"TF\d{4}.*?[Y|N] [Y|N] [-|\d\.\d*]",flags=re.DOTALL)
test2 = re.findall(mat,text)
print(test2)
```

However, this gives me the following list:

```
['TF0876 some text for  Y N 2', 'TF9788 more text N Y -']
```

For some reason, in the first match that the regex finds stops at the "2", rather than the "2.31" which is what I want. If instead of the `\d\.\d*` I simply type in`2.31` then it still only matches only up to the "2". In fact whatever I type, I only seem to get one character from either side of the "|". I don't understand this; the regex HOWTO says that the expression `Crow|Servo` will match "Crow" or "Servo", but nothing smaller (such as "Cro"). In my case the opposite seems to be happening, so I clearly don't understand something and would be grateful for help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within your compiled statement, try changing it to

```
mat = re.compile(r"TF\d{4}.*?[YN] [YN] [-\d\.]*",flags=re.DOTALL)
```

You will not need the "|" within "[]". These brackets already signalize a range or collection of different possible expressions.

Second Option is to use groups by applying "()" brackets instead of your "[]". Depends on what you want to match exactly. Both will work on your given example texts.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using brackets `[]` instead of parentheses `()` to separate subgroups. Try this:

```
import re

text = "TF0876 some text Y N 2.31 - 0.01\n TF9788 more text N Y - 2.3 -\n TF1626"
mat = re.compile(r"TF\d{4}.*?(?:Y|N) (?:Y|N) (?:-|\d\.\d*)",flags=re.DOTALL)
test2 = re.findall(mat, text)
print(test2)
# ['TF0876 some text Y N 2.31', 'TF9788 more text N Y -']
```

Here the `?:` bits are just so subgroups are not captured. Note that `(?:Y|N)` is basically the same as simply `[YN]`.